# viewdidload called after closing dismissing child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a main Viewcontroller and a Child Viewcontroller.

I realized that when closing the Childviewcontroller like:

```
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        });
```

it will just dismiss the child viewcontroller and I can see the mainview controller. No other code is processed

if I close the child viewcontroller with a notification to the main viewcontroller :

```
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark", object: nil);
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

                });
```

then my refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark() function is called in the main viewcontroller and in parallel the standard viewDidLoad() is also called.

Is it normal behaviour, that in this case the viewDidLoad() is called after dismissing the child viewcontroller ? Is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: Which `viewDidLoad`, parent or child?  What code does the listener for `refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark ` have?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called of the Main viewcontroller. To simplify the case I just have a println("test") in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be called after dismissing. Tested, and not called indeed.

Here's the quick example:

PARENT

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(__FUNCTION__)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark", name: "refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark", object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("childVC") as! ChildViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark() {
        println(__FUNCTION__)
    }
}
```

CHILD

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func exitTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshtextviewer_with_bookmark", object: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

FYI `__FUNCTION__` macro is replaced with the function name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing. But it does in my case. Any thouths. It seems, that a new main viewcontroller is started after dismiss of child. I tested this by setting a variable (default false) in the Main to true after viewDidLoad. after dismissing the child and processing the viewDidLoad again, the variable was false again.

Comment: Do you push it in navigation view controller? Please post how you invoke the child from the parent.

Comment: I just found out. I have a mess with notifications. I have 2 notifications with the same name in 2 Main Viewcontrollers which call the same childviewcontroller. I renamed them uniquely and now it works. Thanks a lot . I will accept, because question and your answer are correct.