# viewDidLoad called after calling dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Why viewDidLoad method called after dismissViewControllerAnimated. I am using BSImagePickerViewController for multiple selection of images. So, after dismissing gallery viewDidLoad method called again.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.  

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Start by selecting the photos/videos you want to represent your room", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
    { action -> Void in
        // Put your code here

            self.setImage()
        })

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setImage()
{
    // BSImagePicker

    bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: false,
                                    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                        print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Cancel: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Finish: \(assets)")

            self.submit()
        }, 
}
```

Why this happening i am not getting, i found only one link regrading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810526/viewdidload-called-after-closing-dismissing-child-viewcontroller)
 but not helpful for me it doesn't work as required.
Please guide, thanks.

Update:

Way to dismiss,in BSImagePickerViewController class

```
func doneButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let closure = finishClosure, let photosDataSource = photosDataSource else {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), { () -> Void in
        closure(assets: photosDataSource.selections)
    })

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the dismissing code you are using ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Please check the update code.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you write any view show/hide related logic in your view Will/Did Appear/Disappear methods ?

Comment: @MidhunMP no such code written

Comment: Do not show controllers from viewdidload.

Comment: @Sulthan Functionality is this way it has to appear automatically when screen opens, i thought this way also but it doesn't match the actual requirements.

Comment: Use viewDidAppear instead. You just cannot use viewdidload in this way. Thats why unexpected things are happening.

Comment: @Sulthan Tried it doesn't effect